# customs duties = duties + preposition + customs

Tags: prepositions

noun1 + noun2 = noun2 + preposition + noun1:

a cupboard door = a door of the cupboard

dog meat = meat for a dog / meat from a dog

customs duties = duties + preposition + customs --- What preposition should be used here?

---

P.S.: the meaning of "customs" (for our case when the word "customs" is in the collocation "customs duties") from [a dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/customs) + an example:

> customs -- the duties levied by a government on imported goods: ‘*an inflow of customs duties to the Treasury*’

Comment: "duties collected by the customs office" (although this doesn't seem to be etymologically justified)

Comment: Not all attributive noun + head noun combinations are easily paraphrased the way you desire.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think all "_noun1 + noun2_" were once formed from "_noun2 + preposition + noun1_". Is it right?

Comment: I think I see what you are trying to say: the station master "was" the master of the station. That kind of thing? It depends, yes and no. Don't forget that nouns are used as adjectives and might never have been noun1+prep.+noun2. And customs duties never had a preposition like this. Those are two nouns: the duties charged by customs. It is just unusual because they are both plurals. :)

Comment: @Lambie "That kind of thing? It depends, yes and no." - Yes, I mean that kind of thing.

Comment: Right, so now you know: some of them had the noun1+of+noun2 structure and others never did.

Comment: I doubt it: _telephone company_,  _bus stop_ (examples from Nordquist: ThoughtCo), _cell phone_ would definitely seem not to be (but of course they're fairly recent examples). Attributive nouns are often used to pre-modify.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Note that in *cell phone*, "cell" is actually short for the adjective "cellular".

Comment: I suggest this belongs more clearly to English Language Learning.

If not, could you get closer than, for instance, 'duties payable to the customs department'?

Here, why trust a dictionary defining 'customs' as 'the duties levied by a government on imported goods…' when - who doubts me? - that should rather be 'the department of government charged with levying duties on imported goods…'?

Here in shipping jargon, 'customs' and 'duties' are both used as short-forms for 'the duties levied by customs…' and in that context 'customs duties' seems more tautological then helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Edwin Ashworth commented:

> Not all attributive noun + head noun combinations are easily paraphrased the way you desire.

- *telephone company*
- *bus stop*
- *wind band*
- *spaghetti western*
- *microwave oven*
- *sports car*

(note that there is a continuum from strong collocation to open compound ... and some compounds, like *guinea pig*, are non-compositional)

That's essentially the whole answer; there's no rule saying that you can always paraphrase attributive nouns as prepositional phrases.